# How to create a data driven test in Spock2 considering all values of an enum source (basically as an alternative to Junit5 @EnumSource)?

Tags: groovy, spock, junit5

I want to test a particular system behavior considering all the values (and at times excluding a few) from an enum. This can be easily achieved in Junit5 using the `@EnumSource` annotation. Is there any alternative in Spock2 (or any simple workaround)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Spocks ability to consume *any* `Iterable` as data source:

```
import spock.lang.*

class EnumSpec extends Specification {
  def "let's try this!"(Color color) {
    expect:
    color.name() == ''

    where:
    color << Color.values()
  }
}

enum Color {
 RED, BLUE, GREEN
}
```

This test will of course fail three times, as the name is not empty, but it shows how you can iterate over all enum values.